# File transfer in Java is not working correctly

Tags: java, file, file-transfer

I was trying to write simple "FTP" program, but then suddenly an error occured. So this is a network with client and server and a server storages files uploaded from client, there is also a possibility to download files from server. But when I upload file it is saved in Server directory as an empty file, will someone help me find an error in code?

Here is Client

```
String nameOfFileToUp = fileFromFileChooser.getName();
System.out.println("fileChooserfile name= " + fileFromFileChooser.getName());
System.out.println("File path= " + fileFromFileChooser.getPath());
pw.println(nameOfFileToUp);
File sendFile = new File(fileFromFileChooser.getPath());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sendFile);
int size =(int) fileFromFileChooser.length();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size+1];
int bytes = 0;
while((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    out.write(buffer,0,bytes);
}
fis.close();
```

Where pw is PrintWriter,

And Server

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
DataOutputStream dops = new DataOutputStream(fos);

while(done)
{
    fc = in.readLine();
    if(fc == null)
    {
        done = false;
    }
    else
    {
        dops.writeChars(fc);
    }
 }
fos.close();
```

Can anyone help? Please

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush/close the output stream.

Also, your server should not be reading by "line", it should be reading bytes (just like your client code).